# Installing and additional Make on Ubuntu?

Tags: cmake

For a library that I want to built I get the following error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (cmake_minimum_required):
> CMake 3.17 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.10.2

Now usually you would remove the old CMake and install a new one. But I am using ROS on my system and uninstalling CMake would destroy my whole ROS distro. So I want to keep the old CMake as my system CMake and use the new one only to build that one package. Is that possible? If so how?

Right now I am using `sudo update-alternatives` for my gcc and it works perfect, is there a similar approach for CMake?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, update alternatives is not implemented for CMake on any Linux distribution. It would work, but nobody provides the scripts for CMake.

ROS requires CMake but will most probably work just fine with a newer version, as CMake tries very hard to stay backwards compatible. Instead of deinstalling CMake and installing a newer version, you have to update your CMake installation with a more recent version. As there are no CMake packages in update or backport repository, this is no option.

You can download [CMake from Kitware](https://cmake.org/download/) and compile it yourself or use directly the binary. In both cases, you can put CMake wherever you like. To compile your library, you have to call

```
/path/to/where/you/like/cmake/bin/cmake <path/to/source>
```

instead of `cmake <path/to/source>`.

Comment: Thanks! No the Problem with ROS is when you uninstall cmake it will delete some ROS packages too and destroy ROS for you.